# Add custom annotation when generate backend code with swagger codegen

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to generate sever code with swagger codegen. In my model have some custom annotation like
@Currency

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Size(min = 3, max = 3)
@Pattern(regexp=TwintPattern.CURRENCY)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Documented
public @interface Currency {
    String message() default "{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Can we let swagger know and generate it also in model class?

Comment: You can't do that. It's one of the biggest problems with all of the existing Swagger/OpenAPI generators.

Comment: I see that swagger has custom template, I see that we can change name but not know that we can add in template to do this or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from OpenAPI Generators version `6.0.0`, for Java language, you can use `x-class-extra-annotation` out of the box without any customization to the mustache templates.

In your example, if you have a `Payment` object in your OpenAPI specs and you'd like to use the `Currency` annotation, it would look like this:

```
Payment:
  type: object
  x-class-extra-annotation: "@fully.qualified.name.of.Currency(message = \"This is a message to override the default one, in case it's required\")"
  properties:
     # ...
```

The generated `Payment` Pojo will look like this:

```
@fully.qualified.name.of.Currency(message = "This is a message to override the default one, in case it's required")
public class Payment {
   // ... fields, setters, and getters as usual
}
```

Reference:

- https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/11775

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by using custom templates.

E.g.:

1. Add extension to Open Api spec model:

   ```
   Person:
     type: object
     x-validations: "@ValidPerson"
     ...
   ```
2. Add fragment to `pojo.mustache`:

   ```
   {{#useBeanValidation}}
    {{#vendorExtensions.x-validations}}
     {{vendorExtensions.x-validations}}
    {{/vendorExtensions.x-validations}}
   {{/useBeanValidation}}
   ```

Or alternatively, if you don't have an option to add something to the spec, you can implement model post processor and add vendor extension values dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck with the similar problem and as the result made an example for swagger-codegen-cli v3 and gradle: [Here it is](https://github.com/vitalyros/swagger-generate-custom-annotations)

This might not be exactly what you wanted. The annotations are defined in java code and used by the generated model code.

It is an elaboration of
[kairus'es method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69374536/11947145)

I've started with [this article](https://arnoldgalovics.com/swagger-codegen-new-template) - this method also works, but making a new language proved to be unnecessary.